# How to plot training error , validation error and prediction accuracy over training progress in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib

I am running Vanilla RNN code on tensorflow in google colab. I want to plot training error, validation error and prediction accuracy over training progress without using tensorboard. I am new to tensorflow. Can anyone please guide me. Here is a part of my code

```
       # Model predictions
    cls_prediction = tf.argmax(output_logits, axis=1, name='predictions')

    # Define the loss function, optimizer, and accuracy
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=output_logits), name='loss')
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate, name='Adam-op').minimize(loss)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(output_logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1), name='correct_pred')
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32), name='accuracy')
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
global_step = 0
# Number of training iterations in each epoch
num_tr_iter = int(len(y_train) / batch_size)
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print('Training epoch: {}'.format(epoch + 1))
    x_train, y_train = randomize(x_train, y_train)
    for iteration in range(num_tr_iter):
        global_step += 1
        start = iteration * batch_size
        end = (iteration + 1) * batch_size
        x_batch, y_batch = get_next_batch(x_train, y_train, start, end)
        x_batch = x_batch.reshape((batch_size, timesteps, num_input))
        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        feed_dict_batch = {x: x_batch, y: y_batch}
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)

        if iteration % display_freq == 0:
            # Calculate and display the batch loss and accuracy
            loss_batch, acc_batch = sess.run([loss, accuracy],
                                             feed_dict=feed_dict_batch)

            print("iter {0:3d}:\t Loss={1:.2f},\tTraining Accuracy={2:.01%}".
                  format(iteration, loss_batch, acc_batch))

    # Run validation after every epoch

    feed_dict_valid = {x: x_valid[:1000].reshape((-1, timesteps, num_input)), y: y_valid[:1000]}
    loss_valid, acc_valid = sess.run([loss, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict_valid)
    print('---------------------------------------------------------')
    print("Epoch: {0}, validation loss: {1:.2f}, validation accuracy: {2:.01%}".
          format(epoch + 1, loss_valid, acc_valid))
    print('---------------------------------------------------------')
```

What changes should I make in the code to get the plots?

Answer (score 1):

One such way would be to store the values in a list, then use something like [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html) to plot the values

Example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

will plot a straight line. In your case, you'd call `plt.plot(list_of_prediction_accuracy)` or whatever list you want to visualize

Comment: I appended the accuracy into a list and then tried plotting , but I'm getting error: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: ` a.append(acc_valid)
    plt.plot(a)
    plt.ylabel('some numbers')
    plt.show()`

Comment: It's likely an issue of the array not being well formed. Print out the array right before you plot it and you'll be able to see it. You want to make sure it's a vector and not a multi-dimensional array